# How do I change gem environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, bundler, environment

I'm working on a distributed rails app and want to update a gem.  The problem is on one server it won't update because the gem environment is different.  Specifically, I get two different results when running `gem env` or `bundle exec gem env` in rails root.  The latter determines the app's gem environment and it is wrong but I don't know how to change it.  I don't see a .gemrc file anywhere on the server and the .bashrc files I checked, and they don't export any of the gem environment variables.  It uses `rvm` for ruby.  For example, the `GEM PATH` I would like to change so I grep'd through the app and rvm to see if that path was in a file somewhere and it isn't.  I'm not sure where the environment is getting set, then.  Any suggestions where to look or how to troubleshoot?

Comment: could you include the input of `gem env` for each server and some info about the servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at the man page for bundle, I discovered 'bundle config'.  It gave me the info I needed to find the problem.  It told me it was getting some settings from /home/rails/.bundle/config .  After examining that file, I found it was setting the BUNDLE_PATH to the incorrect setting.  Moving that file aside allowed me to update the gem I wanted to.  I guess the moral of the story is that 'bundle config' (more specifically, 'bundle exec bundle config') is your friend, and check your system for the settings in .bundle/config files if 'gem env' is giving unexpected results.